# Find MLE given a mixed density

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Given i.i.d. data $x_1,...,x_n$ from a r.v. $X$ with density

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{4} \theta_1 &\text{if } x=1  \\
\frac{1}{4}(1-\theta_1) &\text{if } x=2 \\
\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{\theta_2}e^{-(x-3)/ \theta_2} &\text{if } x \geq 3 \ , \end{cases} $$

find the MLE of $\theta =(\theta_1, \theta_2)$.

$f(x)$ needs to be normalized, and this results in $1=\int_3^{\infty}\frac{1}{\theta_2}e^{-(x-3)/ \theta_2}dx$, which is only satisfied for $\theta_2=1$, Is this then also the MLE for $\theta_2$?

Edit: The density is defined with respect to the measure $\mu=\mu_0 1\{x < 3\}+\mu_1 1\{x \geq 3\}$ where $\mu_0$ is counting measure and $\mu_1$ is length measure.

Comment: Since $X$ is discrete for $x=1$ and $x=2$, isn't then $f(1)=P(X=1)=\frac{1}{4} \theta_1$?

Comment: Maybe I should have added that the density is defined with respect to the measure $\mu=\mu_0 1\{x < 3\}+\mu_1 1\{x \geq 3\}$ where $\mu_0$ is counting measure and $\mu_1$ is length measure. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: The latter, since in the case of the former, the density $f(x)$ isn't normalized, right?

Comment: Then the statement in the last two lines of your question is incorrect.  You would need $\frac{1}{4}\theta_{1}+\frac{1}{4}(1-\theta_{1})+\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{3}{4\theta_{2}} e^{(x-3)/\theta_{2}}dx=1$.

Comment: This simplifies to $\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\theta_{2}} e^{-(x-3)/\theta_{2}}dx=1$ (note the negative sign in the exponent), and is satisified for $\theta_2=1$.

Comment: Any value of $\theta_{2}$ will satisfy the normalization constraint.  It's not true that $\theta_{2}$ must be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have $k_1$ observations where $x_i=1$ and $k_2$ observations with $x_i=2$ and the rest are $x_i\geq 3$. Then the likelihood will be $$L(\theta_1,\theta_2)=\left(\frac{\theta_1}{4}\right)^{k_1}+\left(1-\theta_1\right)^{k_2}\frac14^{k_2}+\prod_{I}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{\theta_2}e^{-(x_i-3)/ \theta_2}$$ where in the last sum we have $I$ including all the indices for which $x_i\geq 3$.

The maximization is simple since the discrete and the continuous parts "do not have anything in common".

Comment: In a solution of this exercise, $\theta_2$ was maximised separately with likelihood $L(\theta_2)= \prod_{I}\frac{1}{\theta_2}e^{-(y_i)/ \theta_2}$, where $y_i$ are the samples with index in $I$ and subtracting 3 from each. The factor $\frac{3}{4}$ still needs to be there, correct?

Comment: The scale does not matter of course.